# Why does this aggregation not format properly in my card?

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have this formula to return to me a final measure that is 3.878.

The formula works properly in DAX and returns the 3.878...

However, when I use it in powerbi and select the new measure for my card - it round up to 4 and when I try to change formatting to currency and adjust the decimal places - within the card, the number doesn't budge from just displaying '4'

This is the formula I am using:
In DAX Studio

```
EVALUATE
ROW("Measure",SUM(Sheet1[Spiff])/DAY(MAX(Sheet1[ACTIVATION_DATE]))*DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)))
```

In Power BI

```
proj_spiff = SUM(Sheet1[Spiff])/DAY(MAX(Sheet1[ACTIVATION_DATE]))*DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))
```

It seems like it works - but, just can't get the formatting right so it shows 3.8 vs. 4. Any ideas here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried this with a different style card and it worked. I was using an add-on for the the card style in question. Default works - so must be some type of nuance. Saw the formatting for the custom card is actually in the visual editing pain vs. top ribbon when you format the measure by selecting the measure. So for anyone who runs into something like this - just check your visual formatting options too.